# Adding Eastings and Northings as attributes automatically to a point layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, digitizing

I have a point layer that I am adding to and am working in British National Grid. Two of the columns are Easting and Northing. When I add a new point I want these two columns to be filled out automatically with the Easting and Northing values.

Does anyone know how to achieve this using QGIS?

Comment: You can use the [AutoFields plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) for that. You need to choose your layer, your existing fields, and define the expressions $x and $y respectively. The plugin stores the automatic values into your data. Have a look at [the docs](http://geotux.tuxfamily.org/index.php/en/geo-blogs/item/333-autofields-plugin-for-qgis).

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use the Vector -> Geometry Tools > Add Geometry Columns, and execute both X/Lon, Y/Lat calculations at once

[image]

Comment: +1, can't believe I forgot about that function as I used it only yesterday!

Comment: Unfortunately, this method mises the `automatically` part of the question. You get the coords for all existing points, but new points created after that will remain empty. The virtual fields from the other answer update themselves with every new point you create.

Answer (score 3):

Without any scripting, the easiest is probably by creating **virtual fields** (available from QGIS **2.6**). You will need to create a project file (.prj) for this via the toolbar *Project* > *Save As...*

Then for your point layer, open your *Attribute Table* > *Field Calculator* (see image for options selected and expression):

[image: Attribute table]

Repeat for a "Northing" column. These **virtual fields** will update automatically everytime the project file is loaded. So, when you add points, save the project and reload.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Keep an eye on the field type: it should be decimal (not the default integer), and for degrees with a good precision.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that very important point @AndreJ

Comment: The virtual fields update on adding a new point. No need for save of the layer or project to see the values in the attribute table.

Comment: Huh, should have tested that. Thanks again @AndreJ